# MYSQLI Debug Issue

Tags: php, debugging, mysqli

I've been absolutley hung up on this.

I'm doing a debug on my script. I'm trying to insert into my database, but everything runs fine with now errors. Nothing is inputted in the database. Okay so I forced some error reporting like so :

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

I got some great information & normally this part is quick, but I can't quite get what is wrong.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message
>   'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'explain,date_added) VALUES('Budget','','','Trading','',now()' at
>   line 1' in upload/inventory_list.php:74 Stack trace: #0
>   upload/inventory_list.php(74): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT
>   INTO pro...') #1 {main} thrown in upload/inventory_list.php on line 74

The line in question is :

```
    $sqls = "INSERT INTO products (product_name,price,details,category,explain,date_added) 
              VALUES('$product_name','$price','$details','$category','$explain',now())";

$result = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sqls);
```

I'm on the right line from what I'm getting from my typical debug, but I can't seem to trace it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have an obvious error in the query

```
$sqls = "INSERT INTO products (product_name,price,details,category,explain,date_added) 
              VALUES('$product_name','$price','$details','$category','$explain',now())";
```

should be

```
$sqls = "INSERT INTO products (product_name,price,details,category,`explain`,date_added) 
              VALUES('$product_name','$price','$details','$category','$explain',now())";
```

explain is a reserved key word so use backticks for that

Comment: Oh boy. I can't believe I forgot. I'll change the name itself. Something that may come in handy is a reference for future users. Do you have a list of reserved key words you use as a guide. Thanks again! I can't believe I wasted so much time try to figure this out.